# How to extend dom Node type to have attributes

Tags: typescript

I'm learning on typescript. And migrating my existing code to typescript.

what I'm trying to do on code below is

1. get selection
2. get anchroNode from selection -> this is type 'Node'
3. if acnhorNode has attributes, get attribute data

The problem is, when I get anchoNode, it is typed with "Node" which has no "attributes" property.

But actually anchorNode have attribute property which I can access.

I want to resolve the typescript error. The HTMLElement type has attributes.. but I cannot figure out how to link? or extend Node type with HTMLElement type..

Some advice would be really thankful.

```js
//...
    const windowSelection = window.getSelection();
    const anchorNode = windowSelection?.anchorNode
    
    // typescript error :Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'Node'
    if (anchorNode && anchorNode.attributes) {
        
        const dataOffsetKey = anchorNode?.attributes['data-offset-key']?.value;

   // do things with dataOffsetKey
    }
//...
```

Thanks to @CertainPerformance

I resolved above typescript error, but right after, I got this error `element implicitly has an ‘any’ type because index expression is not of type ‘number’.`

So I finally end up this.

```
const dataOffsetKey = (anchorNode.attributes as { [key: string]: any })[ 'data-offset-key' ]?.value;
```

I think it's kind of ugly. Is there any suggested solution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the Node is an HTMLElement to make TS happy - and use the `dataset` property

```
if (anchorNode && anchorNode instanceof HTMLElement && anchorNode.attributes) {
  const dataOffsetKey = anchorNode.dataset.offsetKey;
  // do things with dataOffsetKey
}
```